# After transferring database code from website local DLL to WCF service consumes more RAM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, ram

I developed an ASP.NET website that was hosting its database code(C# using SQL Server) on one of its locally referenced DLL. Which was situated in its own Bin folder on server. Now I am hosting that code on a WCF service that is hosted on another website with a sub-domain of that website. And accessed as service reference from the website. But after doing that, my server RAM consumption increases from about 50-60% to 85-95%. And due to this my website is going down again and again. Why this is happening? The WCF service has a dedicated application pool while the website not. Is this is the reason?

Comment: most likely to do with your code. run a profiler tool to see whats going on.

Comment: But the code is the same as of DLL. And website is performing the same operation.

Comment: then how do you know its service? like I said - profile it! there could be other factors to it than you know. remember, memory usage wont be the same all the time.

Comment: Because when I looked at the task manager at the server, WCF service process is taking too much RAM. But I will check with profiler and will see what is actually happening. But I want to ask is there any standard reason why this happens? There must be a reason I think.

Comment: there is no standard reason. if there was, then we would never have these problems. could be connection left opened, could be the number of requests happening - it could be *anything*

Comment: So, what profiler you are talking about? SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: for your application in addition to SQL Profiler. the databases should be separate from the server hosting the website/WCF services!!! if they are the same then you have just answered your question in a certain way. however, I am referring to profiling where you think the memory increase comes from, and it seems from the website/WCF Services.